# Как добавить в конец строки любой символ?

Tags: java, файлы, kotlin, io

Есть текстовый файл в котором хранится меню с названиями напитков и ценами. Нужно напечатать пункты меню с прописных  букв (Сделано). И отформатировать меню в аккуратный блок:

```
Пиво......50
Квас......68
Водка....150
```

Как добавить в конец строки точки-заполнители? Пробовал функцию `padEnd()`, не получилось. Вот, что есть на данном этапе:

```
import java.io.File

fun main() {
    val magMenuList = File("data/tavern-menu-data.txt")
//       Читаем из файла данные
        .readText()
        .split("\n")
    kapitalizeString(magMenuList)
 }
private fun kapitalizeString (stroke:List<String>){
    stroke.forEach { magMenu->
        val (type,name,price) = magMenu.split(',')
        val words = name.split(" ").toMutableList()
        var output = ""
        var max = 0
        for (word in words){
            output+= word.capitalize() + " "
}

     output = output.trim()
     println("$output ")
}
}
```

Comment: ну можно `padEnd` на имя использовать и `padStart` на цену и склеить их

Comment: Не работает такой способ увы. Если строчка меню содержит одно слово, то работает, если два (Например Жигулевское пиво), то нет. Куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну все разобрался сам. Изначально неправильно использовал функцию padEnd(length, 'char').Но покурив мануал, все таки сообразил, что неправильно использовал параметры.
length - желаемая длина строки.
padChar- символ для заполнения строки, если он имеет длину меньше указанной длины . Пространство используется по умолчанию.
Сама функция возвращает последовательность символов с содержимым этой последовательности символов, дополненным в конце до указанной длины указанным символом.